# Can I change keyboard shortcuts for Redo in MS Word for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, office-for-mac

All Mac applications use <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to redo the last undone action. All, that is, except Microsoft Office. Office prefers that you use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> instead. <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is mapped to something else – worse, it's something which seems to be un-undoable based on my repeated accidental hits of it.

I've gone into *Tools → Customize Keyboard* but Redo doesn't appear in the (unsearchable) list anywhere. I can't find the mapping for <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> either so that I can reassign it to something innocuous.

Does anyone know of a hack I might employ to 'fix' this behaviour and force Word (and Excel) to behave like good little Mac programs? Failing that, can anyone tell me what <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> is mapped to so that I might disable it?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Their diabological design decision left me entirely befuddled after I pressed cmd+shift+z a couple times, then pressed cmd+y after it didn't work... strange things started happening, and when I pressed edit the "redo" function wasn't even there. It turns out that cmd+shift+z maps to some useless irrevocable action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried `EditRedoOrRepeat`?

*Tools → Customize Keyboard → Edit → `EditRedoOrRepeat`*.

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, click *Assign*, then *OK*, done!

[image]

Comment: In Windows: **File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Customize > All Commands > EditRedoOrRepeat**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accurate instructions provided by slhck, I found I also needed to remove the existing assignment for <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, which was assigned to the Reset Character command. To do that, go to:

*Tools → Customize Keyboard → All Commands → `ResetChar`*

In the *Current keys* box, select the listing for Cmd-⇧-Z and then click the *Remove* button. Then click *OK*. Note that I had to do this before assigning the shortcut to the `EditRedoOrRepeat` command.

Comment: Works without removing the existing assignment. It may be cleaner, but not necessary.